# How can I replace declaration and assigning variable to object to 1 line in multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, bash

I have many JS files which define some APIs and would like to change many of them efficiently. The cases look like this:

```
var someVar = {};
object.someVar = someVar;
```

```
var otherVar = {
/*
Some docs
*/
someProperty,
/*
More docs
*/
anotherProperty

}

object.someVar.otherVar = otherVar;
```

many cases like this where I want to change the js files to have just 1 line.
Example:

```
object.someVar = {};


object.someVar.otherVar = {
/*
Some docs
*/
someProperty,
/*
More docs
*/
anotherProperty

}
```

would this be achievable in a bash script? Didn't think it was achievable with sed, and I'm not too experienced with bash.

Thought of using bash scripting with sed but saw that it only replaces strings from arguments. Would like to make these changes for several files with different variable names.

Comment: Are you using an IDE with a "Find-and-Replace-in-All-File" function? That would be the easiest way.

Comment: For instance, any of the JetBrains products.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I don't think replace here would work for me because other parts will use that var name in the property later in the file and I can't just find and replace the "someVar" with an empty obj. I would need to remove the initial var declaration and replace the assignment to the objects property to be the variables initial assignment. This is also across many files with different naming for variables. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: I misunderstood what you want to do, I thought the variable names were known. What is it about these variables that distinguishes them from the variables that shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: If you get rid of `var someVar = {};` then how will `object.someVar = someVar;` work? Did you mean `object.someVar = {};`?

Comment: Yes I did, my mistake. Edited.

Comment: Are `someVar` and `otherVar` referenced in other parts of the code, or just in this initialization code? Do you need to replace all the other references with `object.someVar` and `object.someVar.otherVar`? That's going to get very complicated.

Comment: It's not clear which parts of these code examples are fixed and which can vary? Is `object` a generic object name or is that the literal name?

Comment: The code itself is mostly just intialization. But other properties might also be under the object `someVar` later in code, like:
`object.someVar.nextVar = {}`. I apologize for the confusions, but `object` is a placeholder name.

Comment: This sounds like it's getting more and more complicated, I think it would be difficult to automate this transormation if it's not simple patterns.

Comment: This looks like something that would be better suited to an AST transformation e.g. by writing a [custom babel plugin.](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-handbook)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr).

Using this data in a file called `input.js`:

```
var xVar = {};
object.xVar = xVar;

var yVar = {
/*
Some docs
*/
someProperty,
/*
More docs
*/
anotherProperty

}

object.someVar.otherVar = yVar;
```

We run:

```
$ txr elim-temp.txr input.js
object.xVar = {}

object.someVar.otherVar = {
/*
Some docs
*/
someProperty,
/*
More docs
*/
anotherProperty

}
```

Where the code in `elim-temp.txr` is:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
var @var = {};
@expr = @var;
@    (data rest)
@    (require (not [find var rest [flipargs search-str]]))
@    (output)
@expr = {}
@    (end)
@  (or)
var @var = {
@    (collect)
@    stuff
@    (last)
}
@    (end)

@expr = @var;
@    (data rest)
@    (require (not [find var rest [flipargs search-str]]))
@    (output)
@expr = {
@      (repeat)
@      stuff
@      (end)
}
@    (end)
@  (or)
@     line
@     (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

It's a straight sliding window pattern match with multiple cases.

The purpose of these directives:

```
@    (data rest)
@    (require (not [find var rest [flipargs search-str]]))
```

Is to capture the rest of the data into the `rest` variable, as a list of lines (strings), and then assert that the temporary variable is not seen in the rest of the file.

I.e. we cannot eliminate a temporary variable, if there are other references to it.

So this code won't work with the example given, since it repeats `someVar`; the code won't eliminate the first use of `someVar` because it sees references to it later.

A proper treatment would distinguish defining uses from references, but then we are getting ahead of ourselves, writing a compiler, when we don't even have an accurate parser of the syntax. :)

Syntax colored code:

[image]